# stuck with the mousewheel, no pan, no rotation

Tags: navigation

I'm stuck with Blender's mousewheel navigation (in 4.0) because the only responsive feature of mouse 'navigation', which in my case is limited to zoom.

-what doesnt work: pan, rotation with Logitech mouse in blender 4.02, 4.01, 4.00 and 3,79. Same with ...  ¿french? cheapo mouse.
-what does work: of mousewheell navigation, only zoom works. About the rest, it looks like everything is ok.  I've done some tutorials with particles, nodes and whatnot. The numpad navigation is perfect, only it's difficult to manage keys, numpad and mouse.

- Though the aux keys are different, the mouse wheel works fine in the 2.79, which I've installed out of desperation.
- Mousewheel also works with material nodes nodes. I was told to install a script, node wrangler,wich seemingly worked,

Y installed, uninstalled, read many false 'fixed' claims in the internets, reinstalled drivers, tried a good number of settings in preferences... no luck.

I forgot: Win10 OS, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz and 16 Gb of ram